# Rest API Responds with 403 Forbidden from application, works fine if called from Postman

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, oauth, postman

I am trying to Post to a Rest API that uses `OAuth 1.0` for authentication. API providers have provided me with Token and Secrets and Consumer key using which I can successfully create an OAuth Header that works with `PostMan`

But problem is when I try to use same Headers and Body using `HttpClient` it throws `403 Forbidden` at me.

I have made sure that there are no discrepancies in Headers or Body or URL

Seems there is something Extra/Less that PostMan does that am not able to recreate in `C#`

```
private static async Task<string> SendRequest(string fullUrl, string oAuthHeader)
        {
            var json = GetJsonPayload();
            var sc = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            sc.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");

            using (var http = new HttpClient())
            {
                http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);

                var httpResp = await http.PostAsync(fullUrl, sc);
                httpResp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var respBody = await httpResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return respBody;
            }
        }
```

Here my OAuth string looks like this --

```
OAuth realm="REALM", oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMERKEY", oauth_nonce="NFcdqA", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="GENERATEDSIGNATURE", oauth_timestamp="1555457636", oauth_token="TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"
```

I have observed that in Postman, if in Authorization Tab I select Type as No Auth and set a manual header to Authorization with given OAuth string Postman also throws `403`, but selecting  Authorization Type to `OAuth 1.0` works, I cant seem to find why is that and how to set Type in C#

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the Postman request with the C# request? What does the Postman one look like?

Comment: may be this would help https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30349

Comment: @davidG how can i check this? I used fiddler to intercept but the entire request is encoded hence i cant compare it to my .net request

Comment: @brainless coder - the given link seems to talk about oAuth 2.0 whereas I am using oAuth 1.0

Comment: What do you mean that it's encoded?

Comment: Here are some oauth1.0 implementation libraries. May be looking into their source code will help you. https://oauth.net/1/

Comment: @davidG The request was encrypted and didn't make much sense ..

Answer (score 1):

In Postman, under the "Send" button, click the "Code" button - this has code generators for every language - select C# and try that, if not generate a curl and verify you have every piece.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's just a way to generate code. This is a good comment though.

Comment: Two things.
1. This is exactly how I'd troubleshoot the problem.
2. Provide a better answer then.
"This is a good comment though"... Well thank God for that.

Comment: I don't want to answer because we don't have enough information to provide one. And you should have written this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This may shock everyone here but DavidG doesn't dictate how users utilize StackOverflow to solve problems

Comment: This may shock you too, but I was trying to help you, there's no need for the snark.

Comment: I have tried that,  generated c# code alai gives back 403